# Permission between resources in AWS CloudFormation stacks and stack independence

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I have 2 systems (A and B) with a CloudFormation stack for each one. System B exposes REST API via API Gateway, which system A calls. I want to have CloudFormation stacks for each system to be **independent of the other**, so that they could be deployed in any order.

I have a problem with IAM permissions for lambdas in stack A to call API exposed in stack B. To create a policy I need to know the API Gateway's ID from system B. I don't have similar problem when calling the API as I use well known custom domain name.

If IAM Roles could be assigned to Groups (like Users can be), I'd just have another "shared" stack that is deployed first. It would define an IAM Group. CF stack for system A would attach lambdas role to this group and system B would attach policy to the group. But that's not possible.

Does anyone have experience in similar situation and could share some advice?

Comment: Instead of Group, you could create shared IAM role with only trust policy for a lambda. Lambda in stack A would use the role as its execution role, and stack b would add inline policy to this role. I think this could work?

Comment: when is he going to create the shared IAM, before the both stacks?

Comment: @Marcin, seems like something that might work. Thanks.

Comment: @JakubBinkowski No problem. Let me know how it will go, so I can make an answer with more details if it works out :-)

Answer (score 0):

you can include the following statement in the IAM policy but this will grant your lambda function much broader access permissions.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "apigateway:*"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:apigateway:*::/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's too broad for me.